# question about how to render html

Tags: javascript, html, ajax

I have a form which contains : textbox1, btn1, Content(div) . 

 the Content div contains the Comments which existed in the db in a table called **Comments** . 
and I use the ajax with jquery to insert data to the db, my question is how to add the comment to the top of the div without reload the whole page . example : facebook comments , stackoverflow comments .

Answer (score 0):

Use AJAX the other way around. Ask for the comments by some `PHP` script that does a query in your sql. Put the comment in your div by jquery:

```
$('div.content').html(resultFromAjax);
```

Comment: I know this and u should put '#' instead of 'div.' and it's change the whole content of the div but not add to it !!

Comment: @Rawhi: It depends on how you define it. If you have an id to the content, it should indeed be #content. And as for adding. Try using some functions from jQuery, such as `.append()`. http://api.jquery.com/category/manipulation/ shows you more of these functions to use (like `after()`).

Answer (score 0):

As with all Ajax, I recommend JQuery. JQuery's [html function](http://api.jquery.com/html/) does exactly what you're looking for.